# Inserting data into mysql from a html table

Tags: php, mysql, html

im new to this but getting the hang of it but i need help on this.
i currently have a php file called Newkpi.php which grabs all the users in the database table StaffList which i want and then put them into a table which i can enter data into. i then press the button and the data is sent to another table called Services. what im finding is that it creates records in the table but it doesnt insert any data it just put in a blank record the code i have is below

```
<?php 
include 'dbc.php';

page_protect();

if(!checkAdmin()) {
header("Location: myaccount.php");
exit();
}
company();
$page_limit = 10; 
$stafflist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM StaffList WHERE full_name != 'Adam Carter' 
AND      full_name != 'Jakata' AND branch = '$_SESSION[branch]' ");

$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$host_upper = strtoupper($host);
$login_path = @ereg_replace('admin','',dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
$path   = rtrim($login_path, '/\\');

// filter GET values
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $get[$key] = filter($value);
}

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $post[$key] = filter($value);
}



$rs_all = mysql_query("select count(*) as total_all from StaffList") or die(mysql_error());
$rs_active = mysql_query("select count(*) as total_active from StaffList where approved='1'") or die(mysql_error());
$rs_total_pending = mysql_query("select count(*) as tot from StaffList where approved='0'");                           

list($total_pending) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_total_pending);
list($all) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_all);
list($active) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_active);


?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Administration Main Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr><br>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="14%" valign="top"><?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {?>
<div class="myaccount">
  <p><strong>Administration</strong></p>
  <a href="CreateUser.php">Create New User</a><br>
  <a href="UserEdit.php">Edit User</a><br>
</div>


<?php }
if (checkAdmin()) {
/*******************************END**************************/
?>

      <?php } ?>
    </td>
    <td width="74%" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;">

      <p><?php 

      ?></p>

      <p>

      &nbsp;</p>
      <?php
      if($_POST['doSubmit'] == 'Create')
{


mysql_query("INSERT INTO Services (Staffname,ServiceAmount,ServiceDate,ForecastForNextMonth,ProductSales,ClientsThisMonth,personnelRetension, totalRetension, Colours, Cuts, PreBooking, TimeUsed)
             VALUES ('$post[user_name]','$post[Serviceamount]','$post[servicedate]','$post[forecast]','$post[productsales]','$post[Clientsthismonth]','$post[Personelret]','$post[Totalret]','$post[colours]','$post[cuts]','$post[prebooking]','$post[timeused]')
             ") or die(mysql_error()); 


echo "<div class=\"msg\">New KPI's Entered</div>"; 
}

      ?>

      <h3 class="titlehdr"><font color="#000050">Create New User</font></h3>
      <table width="300px" border="0" align="Centre" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
          <tr bgcolor="#000050">
              <form name="form1" method="post" action="Newkpi.php">


            <td width="20px"><h3 class="Text2">Staff Member</h3></td>
            <td width="20px"><h3 class="Text2">Service Amount</h3></td>
            <td width="20px"><h3 class="Text2">Service Date</h3></td>
            <td width="20px"><h3 class="Text2">Forecast For Next Month</h3></td>
            <td width="20px"><h3 class="Text2">Product Sales</h3></td>
            <td width="20px"><h3 class="Text2">Clients This Month</h3></td>
            <td width="20px"><h3 class="Text2">Personel Retension</h3></td>
            <td width="20px"><h3 class="Text2">Total Retension</h3></td>
            <td width="20px"><h3 class="Text2">Colours</h3></td>
            <td width="20px"><h3 class="Text2">Cuts</h3></td>
            <td width="20px"><h3 class="Text2">Pre-Booking</h3></td>
            <td width="20px"><h3 class="Text2">Time Used</h3></td>

                   </tr>

          <?php while ($rrows = mysql_fetch_array($stafflist)) {?>
          <tr> 

           <td name="user_name"><h3 class="Text3"><?php echo $rrows['full_name'];?></h3></td>
           <td><input name="Serviceamount" type="text" size="4" id="Serviceamount"></td>
           <td><h3 class="Text3"><input name="servicedate" type="text" size="4" id="servicedate"></h3></td>
           <td><h3 class="Text3"><input name="forecast" type="text" size="4" id="forecast"></h3></td>
           <td><h3 class="Text3"><input name="productsales" type="text" size="4" id="productsales"></h3></td>
           <td><h3 class="Text3"><input name="Clientsthismonth" type="text" size="4" id="Clientsthismonth"></h3></td>
           <td><h3 class="Text3"><input name="Personelret" type="text" size="4" id="Personelret"></h3></td>
           <td><h3 class="Text3"><input name="Totalret" type="text" size="4" id="Totalret"></h3></td>
           <td><h3 class="Text3"><input name="colours" type="text" size="4" id="colours"></h3></td>
           <td><h3 class="Text3"><input name="cuts" type="text" size="4" id="cuts"></h3></td>
           <td><h3 class="Text3"><input name="prebooking" type="text" size="4" id="prebooking"></h3></td>
           <td><h3 class="Text3"><input name="timeused" type="text" size="4" id="timeused"></h3></td>

          </tr>

          <?php } ?>
           </form>
        </table>




                <input name="doSubmit" type="submit" id="doSubmit" value="Create">



      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Would love some help on this

Comment: Are you confusing html tables with database tables? I see no insert queries here. The usual tips: escape your query parameters, don't use ereg_replace, use preg_replace for regex patterns, and str_replace for simple string substitution. Maybe post this abomination on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for some more feedback :P :). Keep the effort up though!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you  want to use `$_POST` instead of $post?

Also, you may want to consider adding some constraints on your table, assuming everything being null is not a desired feature.

Once you've got that working, I'd do some research on security issues from SQL injection and check your incoming data, assuming it's not an being run on a secure intranet.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your syntax..

change all instances of $post to $_POST in the SQL insert query. I think you should also create variables for each $_POST because you will run into syntax issues if you do not escape the quotes.

Here's a quick example:

```
 $field1 = $_POST['field1'];
 $field2 = $_POST['field2'];
 $field3 = $_POST['field3'];

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ('$field1', '$field2', '$field3')");
```

Comment: Please don't do this - if you do, I can hack your database in seconds.  http://xkcd.com/327/  Use PDO and parameters instead (or at the very least escape your input).

Comment: yes escaping the input is necessary.. but the OP didn't seem too concerned with it, so I didn't want to complicate the answer.

Comment: It's worth educating everyone about SQL injection when you have the chance.  I've had to deal with the fallout too many times :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Services (Staffname,ServiceAmount,ServiceDate,ForecastForNextMonth,ProductSales,ClientsThisMonth,personnelRetension, totalRetension, Colours, Cuts, PreBooking, TimeUsed)
             VALUES ('$post[user_name]','$post[Serviceamount]','$post[servicedate]','$post[forecast]','$post[productsales]','$post[Clientsthismonth]','$post[Personelret]','$post[Totalret]','$post[colours]','$post[cuts]','$post[prebooking]','$post[timeused]')
             ") or die(mysql_error());
```

the $post[user_name]

change to $_POST['user_name'];

same to every $post[]

Passing $_POST directly to sql is not good because someone will do sql injection.
Is better assigned them to variable first and pass in the variable in the sql

Comment: Please don't do this - if you do, I can hack your database in seconds.  http://xkcd.com/327/  Use PDO and parameters instead (or at the very least escape your input).